# País en “vía/vías” de desarrollo

Tags: gramática

Entiendo que es “[país en vías de desarrollo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pa%C3%ADs_en_v%C3%ADas_de_desarrollo)” y no “país en vía de desarrollo”, pero no he podido encontrar su razón. ¿Será porque es simplemente una frase hecha? ¡Muchas gracias por antemano!

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus detalladas explicaciones!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> En vías de, con ese, es la forma correcta para expresar que algo está ‘en proceso’ o ‘en camino de’ algo, no en vía de, tal como indica el Diccionario panhispánico de dudas.

> Sin embargo, es frecuente encontrar en los medios de comunicación frases como «Donan teléfonos móviles a países en vía de desarrollo», «Presos en vía de reinserción pintan y arreglan las sedes de Salud», donde lo adecuado habría sido decir en vías de.

<sub>*Fuente [Fundación del Español Urgente](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/en-vias-de-no-en-via-de-1619/)*</sub>

Answer (score 2):

En estas construcciones del tipo *en* + *sustantivo* en las que el sustantivo no está definido, solemos usar el plural, que resulta más indefinido. Otros ejemplos son:

```
Paco está en tratos con Andrés para poner una empresa.
Pili se ha metido en negocios con una constructora.
Los dos países han entrado en conversaciones para resolver su conflicto.
```

Answer (score 0):

En realidad el término a utilizarse es país (o países) en vías de desarrollo. Según el Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas de la RAE, utilizas este término para referirte a un país donde se vea un crecimiento económico que pudiera apuntar a que su economía avance. También a estos tipos de países se les suele llamar países emergentes.

Se utiliza en plural `en vías de desarrollo` porque no solo se desarrolla economía (PIB, liquidez, tipos de economía, rentabilidad, etc.) sino también calidad de vida de los habitantes, en el cual intervienen otros factores como por ejemplo la educación, la salud, la seguridad.